# Compressing simple text to text

Tags: compression

I have a bunch of long strings (16200 characters) that I want to compress. The entire string only uses 12 different characters (currently _oOwWgGmdDsS and, but those can change if needed).

I'm looking to compress this string. I currently made a compression scheme myself, where each time I first put the character, and then how many times it appears before another one is in the string. So if the uncompressed text looks like this:

```
ooooooWW_
```

Then the compressed becomes

```
o6W2_1
```

For the strings I currently have this reduced the size from about 128MB to 4MB. However, as you can see, for the W's there is no saving, and for the _ there's even a loss.

So I was wondering, are there more sophisticated compression schemes I can use? The end result has to be plain text however, not binary data.

Note: It would also be awesome if there exists a library for both Python and Lua for them.

Comment: You don't need to add the `1`. Your decoder can assume that if a digit does not follow another character, then that character appears just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zlib to compress to binary, and then base64 to expand the binary to plain text. Python has both built in. A little googling will turn up Lua bindings for zlib and base64 code.

Example:

```
import zlib
import base64
text = input('Text to compress > ')
compressed = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text.encode())).decode()
print('Compressed Text:', compressed)
text = input('Text do decompress > ')
decompressed = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(text.encode())).decode()
print('Decompressed Text:', decompressed)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems like one asking implicitly for some pointers into what compression is and how it works. Mark's answer works, for longer strings, but I'd also suggest you read [this guide on what zlib actually does](https://www.euccas.me/zlib/#compression_algorithm).

Running Mark's code (edited to decompress the compressed text) in iPython3:

```
In [1]: import zlib
   ...: import base64
   ...: text = input('Text to compress > ')
   ...: compressed = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text.encode())).decode()
   ...: print('Compressed Text:', compressed)
   ...: decompressed = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(compressed)).decode()
   ...: print('Decompressed Text:', decompressed)
Text to compress > some text I wrote
Compressed Text: eJwrzs9NVShJrShR8FQoL8ovSQUAOSwGVA==
Decompressed Text: some text I wrote
```

You can see that the "compressed" text is actually roughly twice as many characters as the input for this tiny example. A longer example input (of say 200 chars) begins to show benefit.

This is because [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

> [...] causes an overhead of 33–36% (33% by the encoding itself; up to 3% more by the inserted line breaks).

So you need to compress your data beforehand more efficiently than that overhead to see any benefit. Meanwhile, as [Mark points out in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40622734/1791856) it's hard to predict independent of the data what compression rate zlib will give you.

Comment: In this case you can predict something about the compression. The question states that the input is 16,200 characters consisting only of characters out of a specific set of 12. If I choose those characters randomly, I get a compression ratio of 0.54. The length of the input mitigates the very short string effect you are seeing. After Base64 expansion, I get a compression ratio of about 0.72.